# Cannot persist lists in entities when using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory (5.0.0), I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BlogExample;

namespace BlogExample.Data
{
    public class BlogsContext : DbContext
    {
        public BlogsContext (DbContextOptions<BlogsContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<BlogExample.Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BlogExample.Post> Posts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .HasMany(b => b.Posts)
                .WithOne();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .Navigation(b => b.Posts)
                    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace BlogExample
{
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I have the following controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BlogExample;
using BlogExample.Data;

namespace BlogExample.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BlogsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BlogsContext _context;

        public BlogsController(BlogsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Blogs
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Blog>>> GetBlog()
        {
            return await _context.Blogs.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Blogs/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Blog>> GetBlog(int id)
        {
            var blog = await _context.Blogs.FindAsync(id);

            if (blog == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return blog;
        }

        // POST: api/Blogs
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Blog>> PostBlog(Blog blog)
        {
            _context.Blogs.Add(blog);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetBlog", new { id = blog.BlogId }, blog);
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I POST the following JSON for a blog:

```
{
  "blogId": 1,
  "url": "MyUrl",
  "posts": [
    {
      "postId": 1,
      "title": "title1",
      "content": "content1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then if I try to perform the GET call to get all my Blogs, I get the blog I just entered above with the posts list property set to null as shown in the response body below:

```
[
  {
    "blogId": 1,
    "url": "MyUrl",
    "posts": null
  }
]
```

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/HassanAmr/BlogExample)

I am using the following documentation as a reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1

Comment: I cloned your repo and it worked fine.  Add a Posts controller and you'll see that after POSTing the blog you can GET the Posts.

Comment: Yes, I can GET the Posts, but when I GET my Blogs, I still get a null in the posts property of the returned Blog. But now I think I know where to look now. This behavior made it clear that my DbContext is working. I am just doing something wrong when retrieving the data.

Comment: You must request EF to load related entities.  Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Comment: Yes. that fixed it. I just added .Include(blog => blog.Posts).
Thank you very much! I really can't thank you enough!
Can we put your last comment as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request that EF include related entities.  Otherwise fetching a single Entity could end up bringing the whole database back.

Should be

```
// GET: api/Blogs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Blog>>> GetBlogs()
{
    return await _context.Blogs
                         .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
                         .ToListAsync();
}
```

See

> **Eager loading**
>
> You can use the Include method to specify related data to be included
> in query results. In the following example, the blogs that are
> returned in the results will have their Posts property populated with
> the related posts.

[Eager Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)